# SSIS Lookup DB and Count results

Tags: ssis, count, lookup

In SSIS 2012, Data Flow, I take in an excel document as my source with 200 rows of records. The excel document has a column "Name". I want to look up a DB and find out how many records have that "Name" for each of the 200 rows. And add this count as an output column.

EG: select count(*) from MyTable where Name = ?

Name   Count

Mark   4

Sam    2

Tim    9

I can't see how to use Aggregate with the parameter.
Row Count just does a count on all rows.
I tried a SQL execute task but again, I can't see how to bring in the Name parameter.

I think this is a basic thing to do but I can't find it anywhere on SSIS. Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you're looking for is a `Lookup Transformation` but instead of trying to use a parameter, you're going to compute the counts for all names and then match based mapping the column from Excel to the column in the table.

Two things to watch out for are your data types (they must match and what comes from Excel starts as wstr/nvarchar/unicode) and what happens in the case of unknowns.

### Sample implmentation

My control flow looks something like this

[image]

The first task ensures I have a "MyTable" equivalent populated with sample data.

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables T WHERE T.name = 'so_18853565' and T.schema_id = schema_id('dbo')
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.so_18853565;
END;

CREATE TABLE dbo.so_18853565
(
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.so_18853565

SELECT
    D.Name
FROM
    (
        VALUES ('Tim')
    ) D(Name)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 9 1 AS foo FROM sys.all_columns AS AC
    ) X(foo)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    D.Name
FROM
    (
        VALUES ('Mark')
    ) D(Name)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 4 1 AS foo FROM sys.all_columns AS AC
    ) X(foo)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    D.Name
FROM
    (
        VALUES ('Sam')
    ) D(Name)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 2 1 AS foo FROM sys.all_columns AS AC
    ) X(foo);
```

In the data flow, I'd have a lookup that uses an aggregate query

[image]

This will compute all the counts for all the names

```
SELECT
    S.Name
,   COUNT(1) AS NameCount
FROM
    dbo.so_18853565 AS S
GROUP BY
    S.Name;
```

Connect Name to Name and click `NameCount` to add that into the data flow

Comment: Thank you so much. That's how to do it :-) Fantastic!!